# Add bar chart in a column

Tags: css, angularjs, chart.js

```js
labels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
  chartData = [
    {
      label: 'Doctors',
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30, 40],
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(81, 193, 190)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Clinics',
      data: [20, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(46, 135, 203)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Hospitals',
      data: [30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40],
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(209, 174, 200)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Pathology/Diagnosis',
      data: [40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30],
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(103, 48, 121)',
    }
  ];

ngOnInit() {
    this.showChart();
}

showChart() {
    //var ctx = document.getElementById('barCanvas');
    const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('barCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.barChart = new Chart(ctx, {

      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: this.chartData
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        //maintainAspectRatio: false
      }
    });

    this.barChart.reDraw();
  }
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ff80bf;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child-div {
  background-color: #6600cc;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.chart-container {
  position: relative !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  // display: block !important;

  canvas {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto !important;
  }
}


.row {
  display: block;
  // border: 1px solid red;
}
.col-12{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.col-9{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
}
.col-3{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
.p1{
  padding: 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-9'>
     <div class="chart-container">
      <canvas id="barCanvas"></canvas>
     </div>   
  </div>
  <div class='col-3 p1'>
    <div>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="title">Dummy Heading</div>
        <div class="child-div">1</div>
        <div class="child-div">2</div>
        <div class="child-div">3</div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add a chart using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) and some related data in 2 columns of a row. I implemented a bar chart programmatically as mentioned in their official docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html).
I made a class 'row' and 2 columns with width 75% and 25%. I want to fill 75% column with chart and the rest 25% with some data. But the div (as shown in the 1st image with pink color with 1,2,3 numbered box) does appear in the same height as the chart. Instead it comes below the chart as shown in 2nd image. I found the issue for this. As per official docs, the parent div of chart canvas should have position as relative which I did. But a dynamic div with class name `chartjs-size-monitor` is added as parent div of canvas by the chart.js library. This div has style position as absolute which causes my right side data div to move down. If I uncheck that position style, then the div moves up as shown in image 1. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks.

[image].

[image]

Comment: Can you share your html code to see what you're doing clearly? Does your parent div have a class col-12 or row? If not you can try putting your parent-div in a row

Comment: Updated my query with html, css and ts.

Answer (score 0):

1. it seems that the pink area is larger than any of those boxes inside it. May be you should change col-9 col-3 to col-10 col-2
2. you can create a css class exactly as the one you inspect on the Google dev console and add only position:relative !important inside it
3. you can decrease the margins in the child-div and make relative widths with percentages instead of pixels

These are the first solutions that I can suggest. But I'm not a front-end developer! I think there will be much better solutions.

Comment: regarding the 2nd point, the div class is dynamically generated by chart.js library as a wrapper class for canvas and that div class has position as absolute. Cannot remove that styling from that dynamic div

Comment: Ok I see it. What I'm trying to say is that: if you have your own css file in the project, then add a class inside it such as .chartjs-size-monitor, .chartjs-size-monitor-expand, .chartjs-size-monitor-shrink { position: relative !important } or give your parent div an id and create a class that will apply only to that id. I don't know if it works but you can give a quick try. May be your dynamic css will apply later and ignore it I don't know! Just trying to help ;)

Comment: I already tried to have a css class named chartjs-size-monitor and add position: relative !important. It didn't worked. The dynamic div still had position: absolute

Comment: Why don't you try a stacked bar such as https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked.html then you can decrease the width of your chart. And I think it will be much more clear than 3-4 bars close to each other for every month?